# AJAX call returning Uncaught Reference Error: Variable name with '$` is not defined

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to make an API call via AJAX and when the results are fetched, I keep getting this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $sum_of_nums is not defined

If you look at the JSON data below, you'll see the `$sum_of_nums` variable within the data itself.

```
// JSON data
"results":[{
  "name": "Some Name",                      
  "TotalCost": $sum_of_nums.TotalCost       
}]


$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = {
    "company": "SomeCompanyName",
    "companyCode": @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CompanyId))                  
  };

  var url = "URL_VALUE_HERE";
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
    error:function(e){
      alert("nope" + e);
    },
    success: function (xhr_request) {                                                                                               
      $("#Container").html("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(xhr_request["results"], undefined, 2) + "</pre>");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I'm not really sure why this error is occurring, meaning I'm not sure if I'm parsing this data correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The JSON being returned isn't valid if it has that variable in it. You need to actually place that value within the JSON itself - not the variable reference. Note that you don't need to call `JSON.stringify` again. jQuery will already have deserialised the response for you as you specified `dataType: 'json'`. You also don't need to set `crossDomain: true`. Nothing about this is cross domain. Finally, your JS code also has an extra closing `})` in the `success` handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason is because the response contains the variable name  `$sum_of_nums` which will not be parsed by your backend

```
"name":"Some Name",                     
        "TotalCost": $sum_of_nums.TotalCost
```

Comment: Just to clarify the JSON data itself, it isn't stored locally on my system.  This data is actually fetched externally from a URL and that is what is returned.

Comment: try assign the $sum_of_nums.TotalCost =0 in your php code and check. it will work

Comment: Is there a way to deserialize this fetched JSON data?

Comment: use JSON.parse() method

Comment: Turns out the JSON data wasn't exactly being fully processed.  The back-end code was updated to process those variables and turn them into static data.  Thanks for the help guys!